# Generalized Attributes for Memory Alignment in GCC/Clang

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-alignment

Are there generalized attributes for C++11 for indicating that a variable is memory aligned in GCC/Clang?

(Note that I'm familiar with __builtin_assume_aligned. I was wondering if there was a way to do that using the C++11 generalized attributes feature)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++11 introduces two separate changes:

- Alignment support with `alignas` and `alignof`.
- Attributes, such as `[[noreturn]]` and `[[carries_dependency]]`.

Both are summarily called "Attributes" by the Standard, see section 7.6.

Comment: Thanks. Googling around indicates that alignas is the same as __ attribute__ but then what's the difference between them and __builtin_assume_aligned

Comment: @Sid: `__attribute__` and `__builtin_assume_aligned` are non-standard extensions.  An answer will be compiler-specific.  The new standard way is what is described in Kerreks answer, but unfortunately implementations are not there yet (or only very recently got there).  If you consult your compiler manual, you will find documentation of its non-standard extensions.

Comment: @user1131467: I think both GCC 4.8 and the recent Clang support this fully.

Comment: @user1131467: I looked at the gcc manual but it didn't really clear up the difference between  __ attribute__ and __builtin_assume_aligned. Could you give a pointer to where I can find such info?

Comment: @Sid: GCC's `__attribute__` is a completely general mechanism. Alignment is just one of its many, many purposes. It's [well documented](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html).